# Reincarnation, the same person or not?

Tags: reincarnation

I’m trying to understand the concept of reincarnation In Judaism. Do the sages say we return or part of us returns, meaning part of our soul but not technically us.

Or is there more then one of us, meaning do our souls split up

Comment: If you [edit] to clarify what you mean by these two options, people will be better able to answer you.

Comment: https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/361889/jewish/Reincarnation.htm

Comment: Look in the Malbim to Yechezkel 37.

Comment: There are several opinions on this. Some say all your incarnations get reincarnated. Some say just the one who did  best etc. But as @msh210 said, please clarify exactly what you are asking so we can bring the right sources for you.